# std::async with shared pointer templated member functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, asynchronous

I'm working on implementing multi-threading in a project, but am running into a wall when it comes to some more complicated uses of std::async. I want to call a member function on a templated object and pass in an argument as a parameter, but I can't get it to work when the template holds a shared pointer.

It's pretty simple to use std::async on member functions, and even templated member functions. I've seen plenty of answers around stack overflow for this specific usage. I've even run some test cases myself:

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

class Bar
{
  public:
    Bar () {}
    double data;
};

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo () {}
    T set_data (T d) { data = d; return data; }
  private:
    T data;
};
```

```
#include "./foo.h"
#include <memory>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  /**
   * Works fine
   */
  Foo<int> foo1;
  auto fut1 = std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo<int>::set_data, &foo1, 42);

  fut1.wait();
  std::cout << fut1.get() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This example compiles perfectly fine in gcc 7.4.0 and returns 42 as expected.

My problem comes in when I use shared_ptr in the template. Using the same Foo and Bar classes from above:

```
#include "./foo.h"
#include <memory>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  /**
   * Doesn't work
   */
  auto foo2 = std::make_shared<Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>>;
  auto br = std::make_shared<Bar>;
  auto fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>::set_data, &foo2, bar);

  fut2.wait();
  std::cout << fut2.get()->data << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I get this error when compiling `g++ -pthread test.cpp -o test`

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:20:94: error: no matching function for call to ‘async(std::launch, std::shared_ptr<Bar> (Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar> >::*)(std::shared_ptr<Bar>), Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar> >*, std::shared_ptr<Bar> (*&)())’
   auto fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>::set_data, &foo2, bar);
                                                                                              ^
In file included from ./foo.h:2:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/future:1712:5: note: candidate: template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> std::future<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type(typename std::decay<_Args>::type ...)>::type> std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...)
     async(launch __policy, _Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
     ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/future:1712:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/7/future: In substitution of ‘template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> std::future<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type(typename std::decay<_Args>::type ...)>::type> std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = std::shared_ptr<Bar> (Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar> >::*)(std::shared_ptr<Bar>); _Args = {Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar> >*, std::shared_ptr<Bar> (*&)()}]’:
test.cpp:20:94:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/future:1712:5: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::shared_ptr<Bar> (Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar> >::*(Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar> >*, std::shared_ptr<Bar> (*)()))(std::shared_ptr<Bar>)>’
/usr/include/c++/7/future:1745:5: note: candidate: template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> std::future<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type(typename std::decay<_Args>::type ...)>::type> std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...)
     async(_Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
     ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/future:1745:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/7/future: In substitution of ‘template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> std::future<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type(typename std::decay<_Args>::type ...)>::type> std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = std::launch; _Args = {std::shared_ptr<Bar> (Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar> >::*)(std::shared_ptr<Bar>), Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar> >*, std::shared_ptr<Bar> (*&)()}]’:
test.cpp:20:94:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/future:1745:5: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::launch(std::shared_ptr<Bar> (Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar> >::*)(std::shared_ptr<Bar>), Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar> >*, std::shared_ptr<Bar> (*)())>’
```

I thought this maybe was because the reference & wasn't working in the proper order with all those angle brackets for the templates, so I tried using some parentheses:

```
#include "./foo.h"
#include <memory>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  /**
   * Doesn't work
   */
  Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>> foo2;
  Bar bar;
  auto fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, &(Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>::set_data), &foo2, bar);

  fut2.wait();
  std::cout << fut2.get().data << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Which results in a shorter error which I also don't understand.

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:20:75: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘T Foo<T>::set_data(T) [with T = std::shared_ptr<Bar>]’
   auto fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, &(Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>::set_data), &foo2, bar);
```

I am confused why the shared pointers all of a sudden make a difference, and I'm guessing it has to do with type deduction? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks to those that responded, here is the solution. The parentheses are not required, and some shared_ptrs were missing.

```
#include "./foo.h"
#include <memory>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>> foo2;
  auto bar = std::make_shared<Bar>(2.5);
  auto fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>::set_data), &foo2, bar;

  fut2.wait();
  std::cout << fut2.get()->data << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `set_data` takes a `T`.  When `T` is a `shared_ptr<Bar>`, you can't pass it a `Bar`.  There is no conversion from `Bar` to `shared_ptr<Bar>`

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for pointing that out. Made the edit regarding your first comment. The error is still there.

Comment: You also have a typo with `fut2.get().data`.  `fut2.get()` is a `shared_ptr<Bar>`.  You need `fut2.get()->data` to get the `Bar`'s data.

Comment: Try `foo2.get()` instead of `&foo2`, when calling `std::async`. But in general just drop this syntax and use lambdas, they are much easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues, I think that using a lambda might help you clarify what is going on:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>> foo2;
  Bar bar;

  auto op = [foo2, bar]() mutable {return foo2.set_data(std::make_shared<Bar>(bar));};
  auto fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, op);

  fut2.wait();
  std::cout << fut2.get()->data << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

You have to pass to the `set_data` a `shared_ptr` to `Foo`. Secondly, the `set_data` is not const-qualified, so you need a mutable lambda.
Lastly, the future, when returning though `get()`, will give you a `shared_ptr` to `Bar` so you need the operator `->` .
You can make the code more efficient moving `Foo2` and `Bar` inside the lambda, but I am trying to keep the answer simple, in particular because I do not know if you want, in your use case to re-use `Foo2` and `Bar`, but you can consider moving inside the lambda.

Regarding your specific code, the following is compiling in g++ 9.1 with C++14, see https://godbolt.org/z/DFZLtb

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>> foo2;
  Bar bar;
  auto fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>::set_data, &foo2, std::make_shared<Bar>());

  fut2.wait();
  std::cout << fut2.get()->data << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

You need to provide a `shared_ptr<Bar>`as argument and not a `Bar` and you need to remove the parenthesis around `Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>::set_data`.

Comment: I had also tried a lambda, but in my use case I needed to return something from the function being called by async and I couldn't get the lambda to do that properly. I will give this a shot, however.

Comment: Try to play around with my code at https://godbolt.org/z/IYSLqQ . If you post your tentative with lambdas I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm just still hesitant to go to a lambda because I know that this should work somehow by just passing the function. I tried changing what you suggesting to shared pointers (edited code in original question if you want to see), but I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: Try   auto fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>::set_data, &foo2, std::make_shared<Bar>()); , see https://godbolt.org/z/qzRlxD

Answer (score 2):

You just have some typos in your code, in first `shared_ptr` example you pass `shared_ptr<Foo>` instead of raw ptr `Foo*` to your function. In the second example first argument `Foo*` is correct, but second one is `Bar` instead of `shared_ptr<Bar>`. Here you have the working example:

```
class Bar
{
  public:
    Bar () {}
    double data;
};

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo () {}
    T set_data (T d) { data = d; return data; }
  private:
    T data;
};

#include <future>

TEST(xxx, yyy) {
    Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar> > foo;
    auto bar = std::make_shared<Bar>();
    bar->data = 42;
    auto futureResult = std::async(std::launch::async,
        &Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar> >::set_data, &foo, bar);
    std::cout << futureResult.get()->data << std::endl;
}
```

As a side note, if you need to run async operation on some data inside your `Foo` class, better provide the interface that executes this async operation inside your class and returns the future.

```
std::future<T> runAsyncOper(const T& data);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I had just found this answer right when you posted it from the previous answer. Thanks for the last note as well that encourages proper encapsulation, but I am not actually implementing my code exactly as the exampled does, so there isn't the same manipulation of class data.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example with the shared pointer doesn't pass a shared pointer to std::async as a last parameter, it passes a pointer to function (you didn't add the parentheses)

```
int main()
{
    /**
    * Works :)
    */
    Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>> foo2;

    auto br = std::make_shared<Bar>();

    auto fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>::set_data, &foo2, br);

    fut2.wait();
    std::cout << fut2.get()->data << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you passed wrong types of arguments to `std::async` and used incorrectly `std::make_shared`.

Minimal modification to your code:

```cpp
  auto foo2 = std::make_shared<Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>>();
  auto bar = std::make_shared<Bar>();
  auto fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>::set_data, foo2, bar);

  fut2.wait();
  std::cout << fut2.get()->data << std::endl;
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/3YXG56ahFKrZs8GB